# What's differenct between AntD UploadFile's status field, `done` and `success`?

Tags: reactjs, antd

[image]

just don't understand what different between `done` and `success` / `error`

Answer (score 0):

Just as the Description says, it changes how "UploadFile" looks.

That's all, and if you want to know how they differ, you can try using them

Comment: What do you meaning? is uploading -> success -> done?

Comment: I mean it just changes color. Its arbitrary

Comment: because I used it as controlled state, I should self render color, extract success file from fileList. So status meaning is important to me.